# Mailchimp - Add Alternate Row Colouring to Table via CSS

Tags: html, css, mailchimp

I'm working on my first Mailchimp Template and have added a simple HTML table. I would now like to set the table row coloring to alternate every row. I would like to use this CSS:

```
 <style type="text/css">
 tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}
 </style>
```

I can't find where to insert this CSS within the Mailchimp template? I have a free account at the moment so not eligible for tech support either.

Would appreciate if someone can explain where I would insert this CSS into the Mailchimp Template?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turns out you can only add CSS when using the "Code your Own" Templates, not the standard templates that you create by default in Mailchimp.